magento 2.4 are map and mixin with false equivalent? Which is better?
Recently, I needed to override a specific function in a magento validator mixin.
The regular mixin didn't work because my file gets called but then also the magento file gets called so magento original function is called after mine and I don't want that. I want only my modified function to be called.
So I tried with a mixin of mixin:
'Magento_Module/js/path/to/file/validator-rules-mixin': {
    'My_Module/js/path/to/element/validator-rules-mixin': true
},


This solution doesn't work: my file is never called, only the original magento one is called.
My second attempt was to create a mixin that disables the original magento file and calls mine instead:
'Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/validator': {
    'Magento_Module/js/path/to/file/validator-rules-mixin': false,    
    'My_Module/js/path/to/file/validator-rules-mixin': true,
},

This works, of course, but it requires to copy the whole magento file into my file and edit only what I need to change. At this point, what's the difference between this and mapping the two files in the requirejs-config file:
map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Module/js/path/to/file/validator-rules-mixin': 'My_Module/js/path/to/file/validator-rules-mixin'
        }
    }

In both cases, I have to copy the whole file, so what's the difference between the two methods? Which one should be used?
As a related question: is it possible to override/replace an existing function in the validation file without copying the whole file?

The ideal approach is to override only the specific function you need without copying the entire file. This can be done using a proper mixin, ensuring your changes apply correctly and take precedence over the original.
